# Newlines from a background process aren't working while ssh is running

Tags: bash, carriage-return, line-endings

I have a process that prints some lines of text running in the background. If I start ssh, the newline characters don't work properly.

```
user@localhost:~$ { sleep 5; echo -e "1\n2\n3" ; } &
[1] 26215
user@localhost:~$ 1
2
3
user@localhost:~$ { sleep 5; echo -e "1\n2\n3" ; } &
user@localhost:~$ ssh localhost # quickly
user@localhost:~$ 1
                   2
                    3
```

I would expect 2 and 3 to start at the beginning of a newline regardless of whether ssh is running or not. Can someone explain what's happening here? Is there a way to fix things so newlines still work?

Oddly, if I throw some `\r` into the mix the newlines seem to work again, although I need to replace the default echo newline with a `\r` too.

```
user@localhost:~$ { sleep 5; echo -en "1\r\n2\r\n3\r\n" ; } &
[1] 7066
user@localhost:~$ 1
2
3
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By default in an interactive shell the tty/pty is in **canonical** mode and `\n` written to the tty will be automatically converted to `\r\n`.

When you ssh to a remote server to start an interactive shell, ssh will change the local tty to **raw** mode (or non-canonical mode) and in raw mode `\n` will not be converted to `\r\n`.

See the following example (highlighted some part with `^` chars):

```
$ tty
/dev/pts/2
$ stty -a -F /dev/pts/2
speed 38400 baud; rows 43; columns 80; line = 0;
intr = ^C; quit = ^\; erase = ^H; kill = ^U; eof = ^D; eol = <undef>;
eol2 = <undef>; swtch = <undef>; start = ^Q; stop = <undef>; susp = ^Z;
rprnt = ^R; werase = ^W; lnext = ^V; discard = ^O; min = 1; time = 0;
-parenb -parodd -cmspar cs8 -hupcl -cstopb cread -clocal -crtscts
-ignbrk -brkint -ignpar -parmrk -inpck -istrip -inlcr -igncr icrnl ixon -ixoff
-iuclc ixany -imaxbel iutf8
opost -olcuc -ocrnl onlcr -onocr -onlret -ofill -ofdel nl0 cr0 tab0 bs0 vt0 ff0
^^^^^               ^^^^^
isig icanon iexten echo echoe echok -echonl -noflsh -xcase -tostop -echoprt
     ^^^^^^
echoctl echoke -flusho -extproc
$
$ ssh -t 127.0.0.1 bash --norc
bash-5.1# tty
/dev/pts/13
bash-5.1# stty -a -F /dev/pts/2
speed 38400 baud; rows 43; columns 80; line = 0;
intr = ^C; quit = ^\; erase = ^H; kill = ^U; eof = ^D; eol = <undef>;
eol2 = <undef>; swtch = <undef>; start = ^Q; stop = <undef>; susp = ^Z;
rprnt = ^R; werase = ^W; lnext = ^V; discard = ^O; min = 1; time = 0;
-parenb -parodd -cmspar cs8 -hupcl -cstopb cread -clocal -crtscts
-ignbrk -brkint ignpar -parmrk -inpck -istrip -inlcr -igncr -icrnl -ixon -ixoff
-iuclc -ixany -imaxbel iutf8
-opost -olcuc -ocrnl onlcr -onocr -onlret -ofill -ofdel nl0 cr0 tab0 bs0 vt0 ff0
^^^^^^
-isig -icanon -iexten -echo -echoe -echok -echonl -noflsh -xcase -tostop -echoprt
      ^^^^^^^
echoctl echoke -flusho -extproc
bash-5.1#
```

As you've found out, to force the `\r\n` behavior you can explicitly use `\r\n`:

```
printf '1\r\n2\r\n3\r\n'
```

You can see stty's [manual](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/stty.1.html) for more details about the misc flags.

Comment: Important background info: `\n` refers to the "line feed" [control character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_character#In_ASCII) (sometimes called "newline"), which tells the Terminal to go to the next line. Not the *beginning* of the next line, just straight down wherever it is. `\r` refers to the "carriage return" control character, which tells the Terminal to go to the beginning of the (current) line. What we think of as the "newline" function actually involves telling the Terminal to do both, and hence requires sending both characters.